# Tor Broswer does not have permission to enter the profile

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, tor-install

I downloaded Tor browser but every time i attempt to launch it all i get is this message:

"Tor Browser does not have permission to enter the profile. Please adjust you file system settings and try again."

I have tried reinstalling it, but no luck.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: The issue is with what the warning is saying. Uninstalling and reinstalling isn't helping because some system setting is preventing the Tor browser from using the profile.

Comment: Which operating system does your problem occur on?